# Align gb4e examples horizontally

Tags: horizontal-alignment, numbering, linguistics, gb4e

Is there any way to make examples written in `gb4e` appear ordered horizontally to each other, not vertically?

It should look like this:

> 1)   a. Short example   b. Short example    c. Short example

instead of

> 1) a. Short example
>
> b. Short example
>
> c. Short example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A solution using `multicol`

You can use the `multicol` package to do this. The examples really do need to be quite small, though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex\label{threeex}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{xlist}
\ex A small example.
\ex Another small example.
\ex And a third one.
\end{xlist}
\end{multicols}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

However, a downside of this approach is that if you put more than 3 examples in a list, the way the `multicol` works will put the examples in an order you probably won't like:

[image: output of code]

### A solution using `tabularx`

Since the `multicol` solution has severe limitations, I usually use a tabular environment for these kinds of examples.  Here's a worked out example. It uses `tabularx` to create the table, and adds a command to increment the counter within the table.

The main limitation of this approach is that it won't work properly with glossed examples using the `\gll` macros. I don't know of any good way to do that.

Also, if you are using grammaticality judgement symbols like `*` you should enclose them like this `\llap{*}` so that they line up correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\newcolumntype{T}{>{\refstepcounter{tabenum}}X}
\newcounter{tabenum}[xnumi]
\renewcommand{\thetabenum}{\thexnumi\alph{tabenum}}
\newcommand*{\tabex}{\relax\alph{tabenum}.\quad}
\NewEnviron{multiexe}{%
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1ex}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{@{}TTT@{}}
       \BODY
    \end{tabularx}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex\label{firstset}
\begin{multiexe}
\tabex A small example. &
\tabex Another small example. &
\tabex And a third one. \\
\tabex A fourth &
\tabex A fifth \label{foo1}&
\tabex A sixth
\end{multiexe}
\ex\label{secondset}
\begin{multiexe}
\tabex A small example. &
\tabex Another small example. &
\tabex And a third one.\label{foo2} \\
\tabex A fourth &
\tabex A fifth &
\tabex A sixth
\end{multiexe}
\end{exe}
 You can refer to examples (\ref{foo1}) and (\ref{foo2}).
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: The tabularx example is exactly what I needed. Thank you!