# How can I put two examples without break using gb4e?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, linguistics, forest, gb4e

I would like to ask about numbered examples in linguistics. I am using gb4e for the numbering examples and forest for the syntactic trees. My question is how to put two syntactic trees in line. I would like to get the following result.

[image: desirable result]

However, to receive this structure, I did not use gb4e. It means that a. and b. in the figure is written in script directly.

The following is the script of this one.

```
\begin{exe}
\ex syntactic tree \\
        a. \begin{forest} 
[VP
    [DP]
    [V’
        [V]
        [DP]
    ]
]
    \end{forest} \hspace{4ex}
    b. \begin{forest} 
[VP
    [DP]
    [V’
        [V]
        [DP]
    ]
]
    \end{forest} \\
    c. \begin{forest} 
[VP
    [DP]
    [V’
        [V]
        [DP]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}

\end{exe}
```

When I introduce the numbering code within this structure, I cannot get the figure above. What I would like to do is to put the two syntactic tree without break like the figure. The following is the code and result I have got from the code.

[image: undesirable example]

```
   \begin{exe}
    \ex derivation of tree
        \begin{xlist}
        \ex \begin{forest}
    [VP
        [DP]
        [V’
            [V]
            [DP]
        ]
    ]    
        \end{forest}
        \quad
        \ex \begin{forest}
    [VP
        [DP]
        [V’
            [V]
            [DP]
        ]
    ]    
        \end{forest}


        \end{xlist}
    \end{exe}
```

If you have an idea on how to implement the desirable one, could you tell me the idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead make a compilable document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `multicol` package to put (small) trees and examples side by side.

For another kind of solution see:

- [Align gb4e examples vertically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321564/2693)

```
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex syntactic tree
\begin{xlist}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\ex\begin{forest} 
[VP
    [DP]
    [V’
        [V]
        [DP]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\ex
\begin{forest} 
[VP
    [DP]
    [V’
        [V]
        [DP]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{multicols}
\ex\begin{forest} 
[VP
    [DP]
    [V’
        [V]
        [DP]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]